# Custom JS file in PHP for alert

Tags: javascript, php

I have a html form that on submission an alert box pops up. This is done through php and javascript. Right now the alert is just the standard alert, but I wanted to make the alert styled. I have a custom css and custom javascript file (`alert.css` and `alert.min.js`) which gives me different styled alert boxes.
Also, `swal` is the word that replaces the javascript `alert`

The problem I have is that, in my simple php script I cannot seem to reference these files to make the custom alert box pop up

How can i correctly reference the custom `alert.min.js` file?

This is the (very simple) PHP:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to      =  "email@email.com";
    $from    =  "email@whatever.com";
    $name    =  $_POST['name'];
    $email   =  $_POST['email'];

    $subject =  "Contact Form Submission";
    $message =  "Name - " . $name . "\n" . "Message - " . $_POST['message'];
    $headers =  "From:" . $from;

    $headers =  'From: email@whatever.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $URL     =  "http://www.google.com/";

    if ( ! filter_var($from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "Please enter a valid email";
    } 
    else {
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        echo " <script src="alert.min.js">swal('Thanks!', 'We'll get back to you shortly.');</script>";
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";
    }

}
```

Comment: could you try to close existing script tag before swal and open new script tag?

Comment: try change " with ' here :  echo " <script src='alert.min.js'>swal('Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are using [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).

So, you've to update your response in html because you've to include `sweetalert` css too in order to work correctly and css goes to the head section.

Update your else section like so

```
else {
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Document</title>
                <link rel='stylesheet' href='sweetalert.css'>
            </head>
            <body>
                <script src='sweetalert.min.js'></script>
                <script>sweetAlert('Thanks!', \"We'll get back to you shortly.\");</script>
                <script>document.location.href = '{$URL}';</script>
            </body>
        </html>";
}
```

Comment: I realised this after posting, I've changed it and it doesn't do anything

Comment: You too have an error : The second argument should be : `'We\'ll get back to you shortly.'`

Comment: I've seen that. updating my answer

Comment: I also noticed that and have changed it too

Comment: This is mostly working, except when the Document page is shown, no alert pops up. I've tried both `sweetAlert` and `swal` for the alert

Comment: You have renamed the original package file names. like `sweetalert.min.js` to `alert.min.js` so considering this rename my answer path to your package files so that it can reference those

Comment: Ah how did i overlook that. Your answer is correct, but i had to add a delay property to the `document.location.href` so that the alert could be shown and then the page redirected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider your php file is generating a classic HTML page. 
It's a good habit to first write the desired HTML file (and test it), then make PHP generating it after.

Here's how the generated HTML should look like (for the script part !).

```html
<script src="alert.min.js"></script>
<script>function swal(arg1,arg2){alert(arg1+arg2);}

swal('Thanks!', 'We\'ll get back to you shortly.');
document.location.href='google.com';</script>
```

now, to generate this HTML code from php, let's modify the last part of your program :

```
if (!filter_var($from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "Please enter a valid email";
    } else {
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        echo " 
           <META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' content='0;URL=$URL'>        
           <script src='alert.min.js'></script>
           <script>
              swal('Thanks!', 'We\'ll get back to you shortly.');
              document.location.href='{$URL}'
          </script>";

    }
```

HTML test page :

```html
<script src="alert.min.js"></script>
<script>function swal(arg1,arg2){alert(arg1+arg2);}</script>
<button type="button" onclick="swal('Thanks!', 'We\'ll get back to you shortly.')">swal Test</button>
```

Comment: Notice that the argument string in swal was messy. Look carefully this point too.

Comment: I already have a HTML file, my php script is simply an external script that executes when a form is submitted. I need the alert to be in the php script because it needs to execute only if the form is successfully submitted, as seen in the `if` statement

Comment: To say it in another way, the HTML code i show above has to be generated in your php file. I'm updating code

Comment: Note 1 : not sure about the META tag position. Use HTML validator to improve your compliance and find HTML errors.
Note 2 : the redirection should occur when the user valide your custom dialog. The way it is, he could be redirected without having time to see the dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work, no alert box pops up, and I also tried rearranging the code so that the META section was at the bottom. Also I had to add an extra `";` at the end of the `</script>` tag. All the variations dont seem to work

Comment: Note 3  (last one !): i advice you to definitively choose between ' and " for delimiting your string. Both are valid, but mixing them can bring headache !

Comment: Without alert.min.js, hard to tell more. Did you get errors in the console ?

Comment: For debbuging purpose, you can define a dummy swal function, like this : function swal(arg1,arg2){alert(arg1+arg2);}
Updated the HTML snippet, it's working. In your case, put this function in your js file.

Comment: No errors in the console, and I've just tried your updated code but am getting no alert popping up

Comment: Please test the last snippet. You will see a classic alert. Now, at home (or office), remove the dummy swal definition, and try with your own function.